# React Native audio change pitch sound audio

Tags: react-native, pitch, pitch-shifting, react-native-sound

I'm looking for solution in react-native to change audio file pitch on iOS, https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound look's like using AVAudioPlayer and that's why it's not supported for changing pitch on iOS. so my main question is there any iOS package that's available on RN in that regard? I tried using bridging native file one but it's very hard to do and needs Swift experience.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i'm looking for package that's able to change audio file's pitch, i want to fork https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound  and editing the iOS part but it's using AVAudioPlayer which inherently cannot change sound pitch, only the speed. so I'm currently stuck